# How do I extend the Grouped Product Block Class?

Tags: magento2, blocks, overrides, grouped-products

I have a custom module living in:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_GroupedProduct

Inside that, I've got a `Block`, `layout` and a `templates` folder.

I was under the impression that I could extend the class and just add my additional stuff in like so:

```
namespace Vendor\Theme\GroupedProduct\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
{
    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(ProductFactory $productFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct(new \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context, new \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils);

        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }
}
```

And then override the template file via:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_GroupedProduct/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
     /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="page-product-grouped"/>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
            <block class="Vendor\Theme\GroupedProduct\Block\Grouped"
                   name="product.info.grouped"
                   before="product.info.addtocart"
                   template="Magento_GroupedProduct::product/view/type/grouped.phtml">
            </block>
            <!-- etc. -->
    </body>
</page>
```

But it renders the product **without** the associated/grouped products.

I then went to `var/log/debug.log` to find these messages:

> [2019-12-05 16:13:07] main.CRITICAL: Class Vendor\Theme\GroupedProduct\Block\Grouped does not exist [] []
>   [2019-12-05 16:13:07] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Vendor\Theme\GroupedProduct\Block\Grouped [] []

So how do I **correctly** extend the `Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped` class for my template file?

Comment: Why your custom module is under app/design folder? It should be under app/code.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh not 100% sure tbh, think I saw there wasn't a code/ folder upon install - tried some (other) stuff and it seemed to work - but it wasn't as complicated as my issue now haha

Comment: `I saw there wasn't a code/ folder upon install`, you need to create this folder. Here is a good tutorial: https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-module/